# python flask restfull receive image

Tags: python, flask, stringio

Hi I am having trouble receiving a file on my flask server from my python client I am saving the screenshot in memory but am unable to receive it on the  server end. I appreciate any help I can get I am lost with what my requests.post has to be.

Server Code:

```
@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload():
    file = request.files['file']
    filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
    file.save(os.path.join(app.config['upload_folder'], filename))
```

Client Code:

```
content_type = 'image/jpeg'
headers = {'content-type': content_type}

from PIL import ImageGrab
from StringIO import StringIO
screen = ImageGrab.grab()
img = stringIO()
screen.save(img, 'JPEG')
img.seek(0)
fd = open('screen.jpg', 'wb')
fd.write(img.getvalue())
fd.close()
fin = open('screen.jpg', 'wb')
files = {'file': fin}
requests.post('http://localhost/upload', files=files)
```

Comment: `files={'file': ('test.jpg', content_type)}` where is your image data?

Comment: Thanks for your reply I have updated the code and can save the image to the disk and post that with no issues but I would like to understand how I can still post the image without saving it to disk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

file to upload should be in format `('filename', fileobj, 'content_type')`, so change

```
files={'file': ('test.jpg', content_type)}
```

to

```
files={'file': ('test.jpg', img, content_type)}
```

doc ref:

> files -- (optional) Dictionary of 'name': file-like-objects (or
>   {'name': file-tuple}) for multipart encoding upload. file-tuple can be
>   a 2-tuple ('filename', fileobj), 3-tuple ('filename', fileobj,
>   'content_type') or a 4-tuple ('filename', fileobj, 'content_type',
>   custom_headers), where 'content-type' is a string defining the content
>   type of the given file and custom_headers a dict-like object
>   containing additional headers to add for the file.

Comment: Hi thank you very much for the answer and the doc I did miss that part my fault.